# setState from json object gives undefined [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, setstate

So i got this problem where i get an response from my backend and i parse it to json then call my set function like this

```
try{
    const leaderboardInfo: LeaderboardState = JSON.parse(response);
    this.onLeaderboardStateUpdate(leaderboardInfo);
    console.log(leaderboardInfo);
}
catch(e){
    console.log(`Failed to convert: ${response} into a JS object`);
}
```

And the console.log gives me this response

[image]

So so far so good its the LeaderboardConfig that i want to use to set the state.

My `setState` function is just an basic one

```
onLeaderboardStateUpdate(state: LeaderboardState): void
{
    this.setState({leaderboardState: state})
}
```

and my state looks like this

```
this.state = {
    leaderboardState: {LeaderboardId: 0,LeaderboardName:"",StartDate:"",EndDate: ""}
};
```

but for some reason this gives undefined so it seems not be able to setState from the json object i have

for your information as well leaderboardState is an interface which looks like this.

```
export interface LeaderboardState {
    LeaderboardId: number
    LeaderboardName: string
    StartDate: string
    EndDate: string
}
```

What Jai said made me solve it i had to change the try catch to this

```
try{
    const leaderboardInfo = JSON.parse(response);
    this.onLeaderboardStateUpdate(leaderboardInfo.LeaderboardConfig[0]);
    console.log(leaderboardInfo);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            console.log(`Failed to convert: ${response} into a JS object`);
        }
```

Removing the LeaderboardState interface here and going into LeaderBoardConfiguration which when i had the interface in there messed up.

Comment: Did you bind `this`to `onLeaderboardStateUpdate`?

Comment: Please provide the full error log. Also recheck the method bindings with `this` as Matthi said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have to send the object instead of array:

```
this.onLeaderboardStateUpdate(leaderboardInfo[0]); 
// [0] will extract the object inside array.-^^^
```